# How to load a second array into the UITableView when I swipe left by using Swift 4.2 and iOS12?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, ios12

I just started learning Swift programming.

When the app opens, I am loading an array into the UITableView.
However, when the user Swipes left, the same UITableView should load the second array and he is Swipes right, the UITableView should load the first array again.

I have tested the following code, it changes the colors according to the Swipes. however, I am unable to load the second array.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let rightSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleSwipe(sender:)))
    view.addGestureRecognizer(rightSwipe)
}

@objc func handleSwipe(sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
    if sender.state == .ended {
        switch sender.direction {
        case .right:
            view.backgroundColor = .red
            print("Right swipe")
            let newCell = goNext(tblView, cellForRowAt: idxPath)
            print(newCell)
}

func goNext(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "chapterCell", for: idxPath)
    if currentChapter != totalChapters[0] {
        cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
        cell.textLabel?.text = genCh2[indexPath.row]
    }
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things: You need a tableView datasource and the swipe gestures have a direction and need to be set.

```
class MyViewController : UIViewController , UITableViewDataSource{

    var tblView : UITableView!
    var genCh1 = ["first","second","later"]
    var genCh2 = ["data","data1","data2"]
    var currentData : [String]?

    //TableViewDataSource
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return currentData?.count ?? 0
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "chapterCell", for: indexPath)
        //if currentChapter != totalChapters[0] {
        cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
        cell.textLabel?.text = currentData?[indexPath.row]
          //          }
                    return cell
    }

    func reloadData(_ array : [String]){
         currentData = array
        tblView.reloadData()
    }






    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    // setup viewController
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        tblView = UITableView.init(frame: view.bounds)
        tblView.backgroundColor = .red
               view.addSubview(tblView)
        tblView.dataSource = self
        tblView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "chapterCell")
        reloadData(genCh1)


        //add gesture

        let rightSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleSwipe(sender:)))
        rightSwipe.direction = .right
        view.addGestureRecognizer(rightSwipe)
        let leftSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleSwipe(sender:)))
        leftSwipe.direction = .left
        view.addGestureRecognizer(leftSwipe)
    }



    @objc func handleSwipe(sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
        if sender.state == .ended {
            switch sender.direction {
            case .right:
                view.backgroundColor = .red
                print("Right swipe")
               reloadData(genCh1)
            case .left:
                view.backgroundColor = .blue
                print("Left swipe")
             reloadData(genCh2)
            default:
                break;
            }}}
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.
However, this is not working . and the currentData is truncating the first few lines as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think your confusion stems from how UITableViewControllers work with respect to displaying and updating data. Ultimately, it is the responsibility of the UITableView data source to provide the correct data for display. You don't want to directly update a cell. Rather you ask the tableview to reload and then make sure the appropriate data source method will provide the data you want (in this case cellForRowAt is the method we are most interested in). I have something that essentially does what you wanted which will hopefully get you started in the right direction.

Its not 100% as you described as left swipes are generally used by the table view to indicate that the user is trying to delete the cell. As the example is written below, the left swipes will never register. So long term using swipe gestures as you describe might not be the best choice.

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

    let dataArray1 = ["1", "2", "3"]
    let dataArray2 = ["red", "blue", "green"]
    var activeArray = 1
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let rightSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleSwipe(_:)))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(rightSwipe)

    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 3
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reuseId", for: indexPath)

        cell.textLabel?.text = activeArray == 1 ? dataArray1[indexPath.row] : dataArray2[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }

    @objc func handleSwipe(_ sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {

        if sender.state == .ended {
            switch sender.direction {
            case .right:
                self.activeArray = 2
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            case .left:
                self.activeArray = 1
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            default:
                break
            }
        }
    }

}
```